# Json string inside Json value field

Tags: c#, json

My c# application want to embed a json string in the value field. But the json seems not valid.

***Json string : ***

```
{
 "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "content",
                "value": "[
                    {
                        "files": [
                            {
                                "valueType": "<valueType>"
                            }
                        ],
                        "recordCount": 1 
                    }]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to add this json in the value field please help.

Comment: It is invalid > "value": "[

Comment: Why does your C# want to embed json in json... is it doing this against your will? Please show the actual code as this question is unclear

Comment: There must be a dupe for "nested Json string as value" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid json for you. You can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert it to the required datatype.

```
{
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "content",
        "value": [{
            "files": [{
                "valueType": "<valueType>"
            }],
            "recordCount": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Below is the equivalent class.

```
public class File
{
    public string valueType { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public IList<File> files { get; set; }
    public int recordCount { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public IList<Configuration> configurations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Title is _Json string inside Json value field_, and question body only text is _want to embed a json string in the value field_.